# 502 (Server Hangup) status code on POST request HTTPUrlConnection on some android devices

Tags: android, apache, settimeout, httpurlconnection, android-8.1-oreo

I am posting some data using POST API call with the following function:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(40000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(40000);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty(JsonKeys.DATE_KEY, getTimeStamp());

if (params != null) {
            // Write serialized JSON data to output stream.
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(params.toString());

            wr.close();
        }

int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || status == HTTP_CREATED) {
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) ch);
                }
                is.close();
                return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            } else {
throw new IOException("We encountered some problem with the request. Please try again later");
} catch (JSONException jex) {
            MessageUtils.showLog(jex);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            MessageUtils.showLog("connection disconnected");
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

This POST request needs to wait for at least 40 seconds for the response from the server. This code works perfectly fine on most of the devices but on some devices the request ends abruptly after 10 seconds.I get a 502 response (like after 10 seconds). The server log has no trace of a response being sent (confirmed by my back-end developer). The error stream for 502 that I receive in my front end contains this:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Server Hangup</TITLE></HEAD>
```

I have no idea as to why this is behaving differently for different mobile devices or different Android APIs. Can somebody help me with an insight to this problem or a solution? I have been stuck on this problem for hours and cant find an explanation/solution to it.

This is a stack trace we are receiving in the apache access log:

```
    [Wed May 01 13:54:54.142877 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 23000:tid 140687508961231] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (localhost) failed
[Wed May 01 13:54:54.142995 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 23000:tid 140687508961231] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
[Wed May 01 13:54:54.143001 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 23000:tid 140687508961231] [client 160.32.32.202:256560] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

The proxy configuration in our server is something like this:

```
    <Location "/v2/">
               ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:9000/ retry=0 timeout=500
               ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:9000
       </Location>
ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyRequests Off
       <Proxy *>
               Order deny,allow
               Allow from all
       </Proxy>
```

Comment: Post your stack trace please.You're not pin pointing the right issue I believe.

Comment: @Syeda there is no stack trace. The REST API gets called and then when I want the connection to wait for 40 seconds I get a response giving 502 status code after 5 seconds or so. I should be getting a response if any action is happening on the server side. But there is no action on the server side and I get a response.

Comment: What is your server, are you behind NGINX proxy ?

Comment: @BorislavMarkov My server is apache hosted on unix. No NGINX.

Comment: Do you use AWS instance ? Please give more details. Client cannot return HTTP codes, only server can. What modules are installed on apache that you use ?

Comment: @BorislavMarkov we use GCM. I have added a stack trace on the question. This is the trace we are receiving in the server.

Comment: Can you also please share some part from proxy configuration, I saw you use ap_proxy_connect_backend, so there is definitely some proxy involved. Do you by any chance have retry_count=0 in apache config ? PS: I don't know what is GCM.

Comment: @BorislavMarkov done...pasted the proxy settings. PS: I meant we are using a google cloud instance.

Comment: @theAndDev thank you, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

502 is actually a 'Bad Gateway'. This is definitely a server issue. You have some apache module that checks for stable connection and that module detects that your connection is not ok.

From the updated question it is visible that the property 'retry' on your proxy is 0. Here is the meaning from documentation:

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass
>
> retry
>
> Connection pool worker retry timeout in seconds. If the connection pool worker to the backend server is in the error state, Apache httpd will not forward any requests to that server until the timeout expires. This enables to shut down the backend server for maintenance and bring it back online later. A value of 0 means always retry workers in an error state with no timeout.

So definitely the problem is in different request and **not** in different android. Please check your requests. The requests you send might be different and server can detect connection as dead letting you think that problem is in android. You can also play with *retry* parameter and set it to default *retry=60*.